# Facebook SDK update from version 4.18 to 4.20: after users update app, they have to re sign in to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

A previous version of my company's IOS app was using Facebook SDK 4.18 while the latest version uses 4.20. Users who were signed in to Facebook pre-update have to re-sign in post-update, and then everything works as expected.

Is this expected behavior, or is there a way to retain a user's Facebook profile after updating the Facebook SDK?

```
bool FacebookManager::isLoggedIn()
{
    return [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil;
}
```

The above method is returning false (token is nil) after app update even when users were signed in before update. After initial login, closing the app and reopening it retains Facebook login session, the problem is when users update the app which has a different Facebook SDK version and have to sign in for the first time when their login state should be saved from previous version.

Comment: Updating SDK versions should not invalidate the token (which is stored locally). We have not heard reports of this from other developers which makes me think it's not a widespread issue. Did you change a lot of other stuff in your app update?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can kinda persist the old token in storage. Then after update, use setCurrentAccessToken to retrieve it.